# How to take the cumulative sum of a data up to a specific date with two contraints

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

[image]

I would like to take the cumulative sum of a stat for a specific date for a specific symbol and identifier. For example, I would like to take the cumulative sum of symbol "ABC" that contains the identifier "a" for the date "2021-08-13". The result is shown in the highlighted cell. A solution that is supported in Office 2019 is preferred. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try SUMIFS yet?

Comment: `=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,"2021-08-13",B:B,"ABC",C:C,G2)`

Comment: @ScottCraner TeelowxD had said they need the sumif up to a certain date, not only that date. Although the language differs from the Title of the question and the details.

Comment: @MarkS. I go by the verbiage trumps the title.  The OP mentions twice in the post that it is for the specific date.

Comment: Fair assumption, I had to double check as I had noted it explicitly in the column, but missed the exact phrasing in the detail. I did write an answer that addresses both, but made a point to cite you for the part you had solved. Hopefully it gets OP their expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the sum of just that date as ScottCraner had mentioned in his comment, although I'd adjust the full column reference to table named references (`CTRL` + `T`) or just the table length to reduce the weight on your system.

`=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,"2021-08-13",B:B,"ABC",C:C,G2)`

If you need it up until a certain date, this is how you would achieve it (to exclude the date simply remove "="):

`=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,"<=2021-08-13",B:B,"ABC",C:C,G2)`